# Перенос данных для разных СУБД в EntityFramework Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть приложение, использующее в качестве ORM EntityFramework. Нужно к этому приложению прикрутить миграцию БД. На данный момент рассматриваются EF Code First Migrations.

Для миграции структуры данных класс `DbMigration` предоставляет специальные методы (`AddTable`, `AddColumn` и т.д.). Для миграции самих данных, 
согласно информации [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> There is no native support for data motion yet, but we can run some arbitrary SQL commands at any point in our script.

предлагается выполнять SQL-скрипты посредством вызова методов `Sql`, `SqlFile` и `SqlResource`.

Предполагается, что приложение может поддерживать работу с разными СУБД (SqlServer, Oracle, Postgre). Поскольку Sql-скрипты миграций могут (и скорее всего будут) отличаться друг от друга для разных СУБД, то возникает вопрос, как выбирать нужный скрипт в зависимости от СУБД?

Я предполагаю, что нужно написать код вида:

```
if (IsSqlServer) {
    SqlFile("Script1_SqlServer.sql");
}
else if (IsOracle) {
    SqlFile("Script1_Oracle.sql");
}
```

Если я прав, то как правильнее организовать проверку СУБД (получить значения IsSqlServer, IsOracle)? Если нет, то что нужно сделать для миграции данных?

Comment: По идее https://stackoverflow.com/q/31344303/5752652 в момент миграции вы не знаете, какой коннекшн стринг используется, так что добраться до этих данных непросто будет.

Comment: @AK, `Database` является экземплярным свойством контекста. Предполагается, что мне нужно создать контекст в рамках миграции?

Comment: Вот [ещё](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294061/5752652) над вашей темой задумывались. Да, в рантайме-то попроще было бы...

Comment: @AK, ну у меня были мысли по поводу ковыряния в строках подключения. Но мне кажется это какими-то  костылями. Предполагается, что ORM достаточно поменять провейдера, чтобы все заработало на другой СУБД. Крайне непонятно, почему для миграции не предполагается того же.